# Calculating betweenness centrality an burstiness

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx, bibliography

I am trying to bulid a citation network with data I got from Web of Science including articles and their references. In response this code says betweenness centrality for all nodes are 0, number of nodes are 83 and number of edges are 82. but I have more than 7000 recorded data. what is wrong in my code? Thank you for your response.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
df = pd.read_csv("D:/dade.csv", usecols=["Cite Me As", "Cited References"])
df = df.dropna()
unique_cite_me_as = set(df["Cite Me As"])
G = nx.DiGraph()

for cite_me_as in unique_cite_me_as:
    nodes_list = df[df["Cite Me As"] == cite_me_as]["Cited References"].tolist()
for nodes_string in nodes_list:
    nodes = nodes_string.split("|")
for node in nodes:
    G.add_edge(cite_me_as, node)
betweenness_centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
burstiness = nx.degree_centrality(G)
print (betweenness_centrality)
print (burstiness)
```

This code Should finally give me betweenness centrality and burstiness of each nodes correctly.